# Incompatible shapes of test and train set in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a CNN network with tensorflow package. My train data sets are 237 images with 100X100 in 6 classes and my test sets are 30 images with same size and classes.
Everything is going well except last part that I want to measure accuracy with

```
acc=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))
```

I cannot understand why it make error while I am testing with test sets (both data and label) that it is compatible “(30,100,100,1) vs (30,6)”. 
Can anyone explain why and what is possible solution.

Note: when I apply batch size 30 (equal to number my test set row) on train data it works.i assume the model expect that the train and test set should be equal number of row that it doesn't make set (usually 70% train vs 30% test)  i checked some post with same error title but i couldn’t get it, in face, i think although the error title was same but their problem was different. mostly they had issue with flatten layer.

screenshot from data set info
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4uY6.png)

here is the simple code

```
…
convo_1=…(x_img,shape=[5,5,1,32])
convo_1_pooling=…(convo_1)

convo_2=…(x_img,shape=[5,5,32,64])
convo_2_pooling=…(convo_2)

convo_3=…(x_img,shape=[5,5,64,128])
convo_3_pooling=…(convo_3)

convo_3_flat=tf.reshape(convo_3_pooling,[-1,13*13*128])
full_layer_one=tf.nn.relu(sp.normal_full_layer(convo_3_flat,21632))

# DROPOUT
hold_prob=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
full_one_dropout=tf.nn.dropout(full_layer_one,keep_prob=hold_prob)
y_pred=sp.normal_full_layer(full_one_dropout,6)

# LOOS FUNCTION
cross_entropy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=y_pred))

# OPTIMIZER
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train=optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    b=0
    for i in range(training_iters):
        sess.run(train,feed_dict={x_img:train_x, y:train_y,hold_prob:.5})
        if i%2 ==0:
            print("NO STEP:{}",format(i))
            print("ACCURACY: ")
            matches=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1),tf.argmax(train_y,1))
            acc=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))
            print(sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x_img:test_x, y:test_y, hold_prob:1.0}))
            print('\n')
```

and this is the error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [30] vs. [237]
     [[{{node Equal_1}} = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ArgMax_2, ArgMax_3)]]
```

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It must be happening because while training your model you might have used **train_x** or **train_y** data instead of passing them through **feed_dict,** as a value for placeholder.

A similar thing was happening with my code which got resolved after hours of debugging.